# Calculating PIN or PIN-like factor without having intraday / tick data

Tags: equities, quant-trading-strategies, tick-data, intraday

I am looking for a method of estimating PIN (probability of informed trading) for US equities without having access to intraday / tick data, but using daily OHLC instead. I imagine its impossible but anything that could crudely re-create it or be correlated with PIN would be helpful.

Here is the original research paper that I got the idea from: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378426621000030